# Singaporean Employment Pass. Minimum stay in the country?

Tags: singapore

If I incorporate a company in Singapore, get an employment pass and assign myself as a company's director, do I need to really live in Singapore, or I can control my company from abroad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the [May 2014 changes to the Entrepass scheme](http://forum.singaporeexpats.com/viewtopic.php?t=93619&sid=f3c302e352cdd341285514d787ed0db2), what you propose is **basically not possible anymore**.  The Entrepass is no longer suitable for solo entrepreneurs, and you cannot open a company without a resident director, who must be a Singapore citizen or PR.

The usual workaround is to hire a nominee director (~S$1500/year) and then get that company to apply for an EP for you.  This is a moderately expensive and risky proposition, and the bar for getting an EP keeps getting raised higher and higher: you're currently looking at a likely minimum of S$8000/mo in salary, from which you have to pay Singapore taxes.

While I'm not aware of any official residency requirement, an EP is intended for someone who is *working* in Singapore, not an absentee director.  You would at the very least need to find a residential address in Singapore to "stay" at least on paper, and at renewal time (usually 2 years) you would likely get some pretty pointed questions from the Ministry of Manpower.

On the other hand, if you choose the nominee director route, you can get effective control of a Singapore company without an EP or physical presence, which is likely what you wanted anyway?

Comment: Entrepass or Employment Pass? Using a nominee director is a viable option too, but getting residency in Singapore would be a significant extra benefit.

Comment: The Entrepass is a pathway to an EP, not a standalone employment permit.

Comment: btw what are possible risks when using a nominee director?

Comment: @user626528 They go rogue and start making decisions on behalf of the company, embezzling money, etc.

Comment: Doesn't the owner of the company have the final word?

Comment: @user626528 A company sole director can legally do anything, unless it's on a short list of actions that require a shareholder vote: https://www.corporateservices.com/singapore/singapore-company-directors/#:~:text=Powers%20of%20Director,-The%20Companies%20Act&text=In%20general%2C%20this%20means%20directors,upon%20by%20a%20shareholder%20vote.

Comment: Ah ok. So it is possible to restrict the actions that the director can perform on her own, but it takes extra work to list those actions and there is a risk to miss something important.

Comment: @user626528 No, the list of those restricted actions is laid out in legislation, although I suppose you could try to amend them in the articles of incorporation.