# Singapore Employment pass. Minimum stay

Tags: employment

How many days minimum does a person having an employment pass have to stay in singapore per month

Comment: There is no mention of a minimum on https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/employment-pass. Have you tried using the self-assessment tool to see if you qualify?

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/singaporean-employment-pass-minimum-stay-in-the-country